# Liquibase diff generate wrong primary keys

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, liquibase

I have a problem when I use liquibase to generate my changeset on an entity with @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)

pom.xml

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <!--<propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>-->
                <username>synchroad_adm</username>
                <password>changeme</password>
                <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/synchroad?currentSchema=synchroad_adm</url>
                <referenceDefaultSchemaName>synchroad_adm</referenceDefaultSchemaName>
                <defaultSchemaName>synchroad_adm</defaultSchemaName>
                <referenceUrl>hibernate:spring:com.demo?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</referenceUrl>
                <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
                <promptOnNonLocalDatabase>false</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>
                <changeLogFile>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/db/liquibase/app/db.changelog.xml</changeLogFile>
                <diffChangeLogFile>target/changelog-diff.xml</diffChangeLogFile>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
                    <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate5</artifactId>
                    <version>3.6</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
                    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                    <version>3.23.1-GA</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Class java

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class MyTable {

    @Id
    @TableGenerator(name = "agent_generator", table = "agent_ids", pkColumnName = "seq_id", valueColumnName = "seq_value")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "agent_generator")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "table_one")
public class TableOne extends MyTable {

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "table_two")
public class TableTwo extends MyTable {

}
```

I am using Liquibase to generate my changeset.

```
mvn clean install liquibase:diff
```

but Liquibase generate 2 createTable with same primaryKeyName

diff.xml

```
<changeSet author="mvallet (generated)" id="1535684993363-2">
  <createTable tableName="table_one">
    <column name="id" type="BIGINT">
      <constraints primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="MyTablePK"/>
    </column>
  </createTable>
</changeSet>
<changeSet author="mvallet (generated)" id="1535684993363-2">
  <createTable tableName="table_two">
    <column name="id" type="BIGINT">
      <constraints primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="MyTablePK"/>
    </column>
  </createTable>
</changeSet>
```

So when I launch

```
mvn clean install liquibase:update
```

I have an error Error: ERROR: relation "MyTablePK" already exists.

If I do not use liquibase but I let do hibernate to generate the tables I have not the problem.

Anyone have an idea? thx

Answer (score 0):

try remove the @Entity from MyTable class 
if you are using hibernate what is the PKN generated?
why u need to persist MyTable?

Comment: MyTAble is not persisted, only TableOne & TableTwo
If remove @Entity I do not use MyTableRepository extends JpaRepository<MyTable, Long>